# variable might not have been initialized in 2-d Array

Tags: java

I have a static matrixMult and static matrixAdd method and a static matrixDisplay(for print the result) and i wrote in Main function a example for test.

My Goal: i want to multiply and add two matrix with these two static Methods.

I get these Errors "variable C and d might not have been initialized".
can someone tell me,what is the Problem?

```
public class Matrixmultadd {

    static double[][] matrixMult(double[][] A,double[][] B) {
        double[][] C; //declar this variable for return the result
        //return null if on of matrix are null
        if(A == null || B == null){
            return null;
        }


        if(A[1].length == B.length){ //check to be equal columns of A with rows of B
            for(int n = 0;n < A.length;n++){//n is numbers of rows of A
                for(int k = 0;k < B[n].length;k++){
                    C[n][k] = 0.0;
                     for(int l = 0;l < A[n].length;l++){//row n of A multiple in column k of B
                        C[n][k] += A[n][l] * B[l][k];

                    }
                }

            }
        return C;
        } else {
        return null;
        }

    }


    static double[][] matrixAdd(double[][] a,double[][] b) {

    //check the rows and columns of a and b are equal
        if(a.length == b.length && a[1].length == b[1].length){
            double[][] d; //declar this variable for return the result
            for(int n = 0;n < b.length;n++){
                for(int m = 0;m < b[1].length;m++){
                    d[n][m] = a[n][m] + b[n][m];
                }
            }
            return d;
        }else {
            return null;
        }

    } 


    static void matrixDisplay(double[][] a){

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
            for(int k = 0;k < a[1].length;k++){
                System.out.print(a[i][k] + "\t");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    double[][] A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; 

    double[][] B= {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

    double[][] d;
    d = matrixMult(A,B);
    matrixDisplay(d);
}

}
```

Comment: you do your return C after your if block, but if the statement never evaluates to true, it won't be isntantiated

Comment: @ScaryWombat actually `C` is never being initialized (instanciated), no matter what the lengths of `A` and `B` are; `C[n][k] = ...` is not enough - needs a `C = new double[...][...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize those variables. In your case it would be something like:

> For C - double[][] C = new double[A.length][B.length];
>
> For d double[][] d = new double[a.length][b.length];

```
    static double[][] matrixMult(double[][] A,double[][] B) {
        double[][] C = new double[A.length][B.length]; //declar this variable for return the result
        //return null if on of matrix are null
        if(A == null || B == null){
            return null;
        }


        if(A[1].length == B.length){ //check to be equal columns of A with rows of B
            for(int n = 0;n < A.length;n++){//n is numbers of rows of A
                for(int k = 0;k < B[n].length;k++){
                    C[n][k] = 0.0;
                     for(int l = 0;l < A[n].length;l++){//row n of A multiple in column k of B
                        C[n][k] += A[n][l] * B[l][k];

                    }
                }

            }
        return C;
        } else {
        return null;
        }

    }


    static double[][] matrixAdd(double[][] a,double[][] b) {

    double[][] d = new double[a.length][b.length]; //declar this variable for return the result
    //check the rows and columns of a and b are equal
        if(a.length == b.length && a[1].length == b[1].length){
            for(int n = 0;n < b.length;n++){
                for(int m = 0;m < b[1].length;m++){
                    d[n][m] = a[n][m] + b[n][m];
                }
            }
            return d;
        }else {
            return null;
        }

    } 


    static void matrixDisplay(double[][] a){

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
            for(int k = 0;k < a[1].length;k++){
                System.out.print(a[i][k] + "\t");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }

    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    double[][] A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; 

    double[][] B= {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

    double[][] d;
    d = matrixMult(A,B);
    matrixDisplay(d);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.this Code works for me.i must to write "new double[a.length][b.length]".just for first one i wrote double[][] C =  new double[A.length][B[1].length];

Comment: Cool. If this answer for some reason suits your Q. consider it approved( ✓ below vote count 1 of the answer ) @Navidms

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize variables C and d before to use them, because Java sees arrays as objects and they are allocated in Heap memory.

`double[][] C = new double[A.length][B[1].length]`

`double[][] d = new double[a.length][b[1].length]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have conditional statements in your `matrixMult` method there is a possibility that the condition is never met. So your declaration

```
 double[][] C;
```

might never be initialized which will result in an error in

```
return C;
```

So you can fix it by initializing it e.g.

```
 double[][] C = new double[length][length]; // your actual dimensions
```

Besides that, you are missing the allocation statement for the `C` array in your if-statements. You can not assign a value to an un-initialized array.

Comment: actually the error must (also) be occurring before at ` C[n][k] = 0.0;` and the conditions don't matter, there is no initialization of `C` at all.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Yes, this is my last statement in the answer.

Comment: but the part about the conditionals is wrong (and being exact "**can** fix it" is also wrong; there is no alternative, you must use `new double[.][.]`)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I said that?

Comment: very first sentence: "Since you have conditional statements in your matrixMult method t**here is a possibility** that the condition is never met..." and later "... **might** never be initialized..."

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger We can stop here. That is the reasoning why the compiler is complaining in the first place.

Comment: OK,but that is not correct reasoning- the compiler will already have complained at `C[n][k] = 0.0;` and not because there is "a possibility that the condition is never met" - but seems like you don't understand this, maybe my English is too bad...

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised dimension of array variable therefore compiler will not know the size that array need to be allotted.

double[][] C=new double[A.length][B[0].length];
double[][] d=new double[b.length][b[0].length];

also in your code at many places you have used 1 based index for measuring count of column in 2D array which can result into violation of memory access(OutofBound Exception)

here is modified programme.

```
public class Matrixmultadd {

static double[][] matrixMult(double[][] A,double[][] B) {
    double[][] C=new double[A.length][B[0].length]; //declar this variable for return the result
    //return null if on of matrix are null
    if(A == null || B == null){
        return null;
    }


    if(A[0].length == B.length){ //check to be equal columns of A with rows of B
        for(int n = 0;n < A.length;n++){//n is numbers of rows of A
            for(int k = 0;k < B[0].length;k++){
                C[n][k] = 0.0;
                 for(int l = 0;l < A[0].length;l++){//row n of A multiple in column k of B
                    C[n][k] += A[n][l] * B[l][k];

                }
            }

        }
    return C;
    } else {
    return null;
    }

}


static double[][] matrixAdd(double[][] a,double[][] b) {

//check the rows and columns of a and b are equal
    if(a.length == b.length && a[0].length == b[0].length){
        int row=b.length;
        int col=b[0].length;
        double[][] d=new double[row][col]; //declar this variable for return the result            
        for(int n = 0;n <row;n++){
            for(int m = 0;m <col;m++){
                d[n][m] = a[n][m] + b[n][m];
            }
        }
        return d;
    }else {
        return null;
    }

} 


static void matrixDisplay(double[][] a){
    int row=a.length;
    int col=a[0].length;
    for(int i = 0; i < row;i++){
        for(int k = 0;k < col;k++){
            System.out.print(a[i][k] + "\t");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }

}
```

public static void main(String[] args){
    double[][] A = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};

```
double[][] B= {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

double[][] d;
d = matrixMult(A,B);
matrixDisplay(d);
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long have you been using Java. In java, use array, you have to

```
1. create a block of memory for it and assign it to a reference
double[][] matrix; // now, matrix == null
matrix = new double[10][10]; // now matrix is the address of the memory
2. initialize it 
matrix[0][3]=0
3. access it
System.out.println(matrix[0][3])
```

In your case, both C and d are declared in the above first step without assigning any block of memory for it and leaving as null, which means when you initialize or access it you will trigger null pointer exception

```
double[][] C; //declar this variable for return the result return null if on of matrix are null
double[][] d; //declar this variable for return the result
```

In you case, please add following to fix it.

```
double[][] C = new double[A.length][B[1].length]
double[][] d = new double[b.length][b[1].length]
```

Java array usage, this might be good example 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: thank you for your declaration, i am very new(starter) in java.